# How to add a cicle in front of an image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, less

I'm trying to add a circle (the circle will contains an icon) in front of an image.  My code works fine, but only in big display; 1,224 and up..However, this is not the case for tablet and mobile...So, my question is: How can I fix my code and make it works for all devices, without using `@media`.  If `@media` is the only solution, then I will go for it..

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="service-box">
                    <div class="service-circle" >
                        <!--Add icon inside circle -->
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-bg" style="background-color:  black;"> 
                    <!--  Insert img-->
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="service-text">
                        <h3>
                            ENTER TITLE
                        
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

**CSS/LESS**

```
.service-box {
    
    
    
    .service-circle{
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: #000;
        line-height: 500px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        left: 30%;
        margin-top: 65%;
        border: 5px solid #e6ab43;
        
        
    }
    
    .service-bg {
        height: 250px;
        border:1px solid black;
        img{
            
            height: 100%;
        }
        
    }
    
    .service-text {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 30%;
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

[image]

UPDATE:

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Therefore, I'm using `col-sm-3`.

Comment: your code sample is unnecessarily complex, many irrelevant divs and wrappers, and we have no idea what rules you have for classes like: 'col-md-3', 'service-box' and 'row'.

having said that, you can try using % based values instead of px

Comment: @MichaelB Hii, Im using col-md-3 because I will have four of those...the black square is an image, the white circle is a circle that will contain an icon, then we have the title for each box..Also, the code works fine, the only problem is when it comes to mobile and table ..that the circle move up or down but it doesn't stay in the center between the image and the outside (title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move your `service-circle` element inside your `service-bg`, you can then align it using `transform: translate`

```css
.service-box {
background: red;
}
    .service-bg {
        position: relative;               /*  added */
        height: 250px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
        img{
            height: 100%;
        }

    .service-circle{
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: #000;
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;                          /*  added  */
        top: 100%;                          /*  added  */
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);    /*  added  */
        border: 5px solid #e6ab43;
    }

    .service-text {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 80px;                   /*  changed */
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="service-box">
      <div class="service-bg" style="background-color:  black;">
        <!--  Insert img-->

      <div class="service-circle">
        <!--Add icon inside circle -->

      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="service-text">
        <h3>
          ENTER TITLE

        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">


  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">


  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer...but your circle is inside the black background and it should on the line between black and red background...again, the image that i posted means that the code work fines...the only problem is when it is in mobile..that the circle get out of place, and i didn't want to use `@media` because then I will be adding more line for each device

Comment: YOUUUU!!! AREEEE!! THEEE MANN!! or woman..not sure..l o l jee but thank you sooooo muchh!!!

Comment: @ArielMaduro Updated my answer. You can't position that circle with the existing markup at that position, unless you know the exact height of the image. By doing what I suggest, it will work regardless....and I am a gentleman :)

Comment: Thankk you sooo much!